# Styling Website for mobile platform. Why are there two resolutions for one phone?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive, screen-resolution

why is there a discrepancy between desktop browser's resolution of iphone X and actual resolution?

Developer mode (iphone X):  375 x 812 on chrome/firefox

Specs from other sites: 1125 x 2436 on (http://screensiz.es/iphone-x)

Which one do i follow for web css styling ?

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_display - a single pixel (in the "make this element 300 pixels" CSS sense) can be four or nine *physical* pixels in higher resolution screens).

Answer (score 0):

375 x 812 pixel listed in the developer window for iphone X is for designing. If you want to know why, read below.

"The iPhone 7 (and more or less every modern smartphone) has a high-density screen, (Apple calls them Retina Displays), with a pixel ratio of 2.0 or, in other words, two iPhone7 screen pixels equal one CSS pixel. The Samsung Galaxy S8+ has an amazing pixel ratio of 4.0 giving it an impressive 1440 × 2960 device resolution. By the way, I’m writing pixel ratio values in decimal notation because apart from Apple (that only uses whole-number pixel ratios), other vendors implement pixel ratios in decimal form, like the 2.4 value of the Microsoft Lumia 1020, or the 1.5 value of the Samsung Galaxy S."

"CSS Pixel = Device Pixels / Device Pixel Ratio"

"Our media query to work properly has to reference css pixels, so those 750 and 1334 become 375 and 667 respectivly. If we compare them to the physical screen pixels, CSS pixels are basically “reference pixels” or in other words “virtual”."

source: https://medium.com/@flik185/understanding-device-resolution-for-web-design-and-development-3bb4a5183478